# Wrong values in conversion from time_t and tm

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have to do two conversion functions, from time_t to tm and from tm to time_t.

This is the first:

```
string2time(string str){

time_t rawtime;
time(&rawtime);
tm* timeInfo = localtime(&rawtime);

stringstream ss(str);
string date;
string time;
getline(ss,date,' ');
getline(ss,time,' ');

string word;
//now we work with date..
stringstream sdate(date);

getline(sdate,word,'-');
timeInfo->tm_year = atoi(word.c_str()) -1900;

getline(sdate,word,'-');
timeInfo->tm_mon = atoi(word.c_str())-1;

getline(sdate,word,'-');
timeInfo->tm_mday = atoi(word.c_str());

//and time...
stringstream stime(time);

getline(stime,word,':');
timeInfo->tm_hour = atoi(word.c_str());

getline(stime,word,':');
timeInfo->tm_min = atoi(word.c_str());

getline(stime,word,':');
timeInfo->tm_sec = atoi(word.c_str());

return mktime(timeInfo);
       }
```

and this is the second:

```
time2str(time_t t){
tm* myT;

myT = localtime(&t);
    //here i have to explore myT structure in order to build a proper string

   }
```

I got wrong values anyway..starting with 2013-03-10 00:00:00
in the tm structure I get 2013-04-21 18:16:29 ... why?

**edit:
made some progress! This code works all time BUT when hour is 00!**

Comment: Here's a hint: 110 appears to be the day of the *year* not day of the month (the current day)

Comment: Yes I called wrong field,anyway it still doesn't work...

Comment: how are you calling these functions?

Comment: ?can you explain what you mean?

Comment: well the time() function gets the current time. So it will overwrite any input into that function. So I'm curious how you expect to use these functions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, was just an error in the string conversion...sorry for troumble.